# Apache-Jena Download

Tags: jena

I have downloaded apache-jena and when I try to run "sparql.bat --version" I get this : "Error: Could not find or load main class Files\jena-4.10.0\apache-jena\bat\lib\*;:C:\Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\jena-4/10/0\apache-jena\bat\lib\*;:C:\Program"
Any help would be great!

I tried redownloading it and changing the path

Comment: Seems like JENAROOT isn't set correctly. Be careful of spaces.
What did you try?